# Search does not find all posts in Rails. Just 2-3 of them

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search

I wrote search function for my site. It works. But(!) it finds not all of posts. Just some of them(2-3). But when I search it in database it finds all and more results.

My model:

```
def self.search(query)
    where("title like ?", "%#{query}%")
end
```

Controller:

```
if params[:search]
  @posts = Post.search(params[:search]).order("id DESC").limit(10)
else
  @posts = Post.all.order('id DESC').limit(10)
end
```

And in views:

```
<%= form_tag('/find', :method => "get", id: "search-form") do %>
          <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], :class => "search" %>
          <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
      <% end %>

<div class="posts">
    <% @posts.each do |post| %>
        <%= post.title %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Why it does not prints all results?

Answer (score 0):

few changes:
Modal

`def self.search(query)
    where("title like :title", title: "%#{query.strip.chomp}%")
end`

controller

`if params.has_key?(:search)
  @posts = Post.search(params[:search]).order("id DESC").limit(10)
else
  @posts = Post.all.order('id DESC').limit(10)
end`

Try this and if this still doesn't work, come back with a sample app that reproduce this problem.

Comment: The next error: `mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%'new'%)  ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10' at line 1: SELECT  `posts`.* FROM `posts`  WHERE (title like %'new'%)  ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10`

Comment: Try the updated code for modal. does this still produce an error?